# Android: load image

Tags: android

Trying to load and display image from server.

```
public static Bitmap loadImageByURL(final String url,
        final Context context, final HttpClient httpClient) {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                data = entity.getContent();
            }
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

But bitmap is always null !!! What I do wrong ? URL is fine, its works in browser and on iOS.

EDIT 1:

when I open url in browser, its shows me something like that:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQO DwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSgBBwcHCggK EwoKEygaFhooKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo KCgoKCgoKCgoKP/AABEIAZABLAMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAGiAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAA AAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQci cRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeo qaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5 +gEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoLEQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncA AQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYn
```

What is that ? )

Comment: did u try it with different image urls?

Comment: check this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-image-in-sdcard.html

Comment: may be the thing you are getting in browser is the Base64 encoded bitmap image.

Comment: what you wanna try?show us sample url from where you are downloading the images?

Comment: You was write. Image was base64 encoded. Thanks....

Comment: then just change image url in normal from like this. byte[] encBytes = imageUrl.getBytes();
       String newImageUrl = Base64.encodeToString(encBytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);

Answer (score 0):

First, create a connection with net.

```
InputStream iStream=null;

URL imgUrl = new URL(strImageURL);
//strImageUR   image url you want to download. 

URLConnection urlCon = imgUrl.openConnection();
iStream = urlCon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(iStream,128);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
int current = 0;

while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
{
    baf.append((byte) current);
}
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
  baf.toByteArray(), 
  0, 
  baf.toByteArray().length());
```

This should work.